# How to prevent receiving broadcast message

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a service which has a countdown timer. After the end of the  countdown timer, this service sends a broadcast message. I use the following code to send the message:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("CancelEvents");
intent.putExtra("message", "cancelled");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(TimerClass.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I have another activity which has a broadcast receiver. This is the code I use to receive the broadcast message:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(cancelReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("CancelEvents"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver cancelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        if (message.equals("cancelled"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Your Ride Got Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

The receiving works fine, but the problem is the message is received by all other activities too which don't have a receiver. How to stop this?

Comment: Use unique intent filter.

Comment: "But, the problem is the message is received by all other activities too which doesn't have a receiver." - Please explain what that means, exactly. How are any other components receiving a broadcast without a Receiver?

Comment: the toast is shown on any activity i open

Comment: Are your other Activities extending this Activity?

Comment: no.. it doesn't..

Comment: It's not that the other Activities are getting the broadcast, then. It's that the Receiver registered in that Activity is still active. Unregister it in `onPause()`, and register it in `onResume()`, instead of `onCreate()`.

Comment: @MikeM. I think start/stop is better, as if you use pause/resume it would unsubscribe when interacting with another app in split-screen mode, although still remain fully visible

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer Depends on the OP's desired behavior. I was just making a suggestion. You might want to point out the difference to the OP, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the Broadcast subscription code to a different part of your lifecycle.

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(cancelReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter("CancelEvents"));
        }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(cancelReceiver);
    }
```

Explanation: Your Activity in in the background, but it is still subscribed, and is showing the Toast messages, not the other Activities.

Comment: I don't think the activity is in background. I use `this.finish()` to get out of that activity.

Comment: Doesn't matter. `cancelReceiver` is an anonymous class and maintains a reference to your Activity, so it's still there, in the finished state. So actually, your current code also leaks the Activity. Try as I propose, move subscription from onCreate to onStart.

Answer (score 1):

Unregister your broadcast by defining in onStop() callback of activity in which activity you have registered cancelReceiver in onCreate()...

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(cancelReceiver);
    }
```

Comment: If we register in **onCreate()**, then better place to unregister is **onDestroy()**.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran if your activity in which you registered your broadcast is not destroyed and another activity comes upon that activity then broadast will also fire that was what problem he is facing.

Comment: In that case we should register in onStart() and unregister in onStop(), We should not register in onCreate and unregister in onStop(), we can take your senario, We unregister in onStop and we are coming back to same activity, in that case even though we are in this screen we will no get anything because we already unregistered.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran yes we should register in onStart and unregister in onStop(), you have explained correctly bro.